# Deployment- Java Application

Tags: bundle, java, launch4j

I have created a Java application. And its ready for deployment.

I have made jar file from my code. wrapped it using launch4j and bundled jre with it and accessing my exe file(generated by launch4j). 
So,No need to install JRE and Everything works fine.

But one small problem is that my Exe file has to be at some predefined relative path to the Bundled JRE.

For example let say user has installed it in E:/(My Soft) where My soft contains JRE files an my Exe file. Now if user copies the exe file to his desktop then he will not be able to execute it.

So, I want to is there any way i can bundle jre within my exe or any other tweek so that user can Execute the exe file from anywhere on his pc ?

Comment: Copying an exe file out of its install is typically not going to work for any application.  That's what shortcuts/symlinks are for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one option to bundle JRE with exe is to create a Portable Edition app with for example [jPortable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable). So you can execute exe anywhere on the PC without installing JRE. But the better option is to create a custom installer which will check current installation of JRE in the client PC and install it as an required option if no other compatible JRE found.

Answer (score 2):

Try use jnlp starter for your programms. Read more in official oracle documentation [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlp.html)

Comment: Thanks Rinat for this suggestion. 
But i forgot to mention that many users of this app do not have internet connection.So this wont be feasible i think !